# Fatal error: Class 'Google_AssertionCredentials'

Tags: php, oauth, google-drive-api

I had to forfeit creating a folder in OneDrive, for the time being.  I switched over to Google Drive, and I am having a little bit more success.

So I am trying to create a folder in Google Drive, but I am getting the subject error message.

```
<?php
  require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
  require_once 'vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php';
  require_once 'vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/Drive.php';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setClientId('myclientID');
  $client->setClientSecret('myclientSecret');
  $client->setRedirectUri('myredirectURI');
  $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'));

  session_start();

  function buildService() {//function for first build up service
    global $DRIVE_SCOPE, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH;
    $key = file_get_contents($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
    $auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,array($DRIVE_SCOPE),$key);
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setUseObjects(true);
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
    return new Google_DriveService($client);
  }

  function createPublicFolder($service, $folderName) {
    $file = new Google_DriveFile();
    $file->setTitle($folderName);
    $file->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');

    $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    ));

    $permission = new Google_Permission();
    $permission->setValue('me');
    $permission->setType('anyone');
    $permission->setRole('writer');

    $service->permissions->insert(
      $createdFile->getId(), $permission);
      return $createdFile;
  }


  $DRIVE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
  $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'my.email@mine.com';
  $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = 'main docs dummy-x456d55d8371.p12';

  $service=buildService();
  $folderName='root_test';
  $parent=createPublicFolder($service, $folderName);
?>
```

Here is the exact error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Google_AssertionCredentials' not found
```

The error lead me to believe something is wrong with the OAuth, but I am not sure what exactly I am missing.  I figured the autoload.php handles that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the version you’re using:

- For 1.0, you’re probably looking for `Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials`.
- For 2.0, that class [was removed](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#google_auth_assertioncredentials-has-been-removed).